# Vue component not updating properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a basic app where the users can leave reviews for a store. Each time a new review is added, I call the get_reviews() function and update the list.

Everything works, but for some reason, the component managing the stars doesn't update in real time and I have to refresh the page in order to get the right value. If I don't refresh the page, the amount of stars I see for the new review is the same of the last that was added.

Here is my component code:

```
Vue.component('star-rating', {

  props: {
    'value': Number,
    'name': String,
    'id': String,
    'disabled': Boolean,
    'required': Boolean
  },



  template: '<span class="star-rating">\
        <label class="star-rating__star" v-for="rating in ratings" \
        :class="{\'is-selected\': ((mutableValue >= rating) && mutableValue != null), \'is-disabled\': disabled}" \
        v-on:click="set(rating)" v-on:mouseover="star_over(rating)" v-on:mouseout="star_out">\
        <input class="star-rating star-rating__checkbox" type="radio" mutable-value="rating" name="name" \
        v-model="mutableValue" :disabled="disabled">★</label></span>',

  /*
   * Initial state of the component's data.
   */
  data: function() {
    return {
      mutableValue: this.value,
      temp_value: null,
      ratings: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    };

  },

  methods: {
    /*
     * Behaviour of the stars on mouseover.
     */
    star_over: function(index) {
      var self = this;

      if (!this.disabled) {
        this.temp_value = this.mutableValuevalue;
        return this.mutableValue = index;
      }

    },

    /*
     * Behaviour of the stars on mouseout.
     */
    star_out: function() {
      var self = this;

      if (!this.disabled) {
        return this.mutableValue = this.temp_value;
      }
    },

    /*
     * Set the rating of the score
     */
    set: function(value) {
      var self = this;
      this.$parent.$emit('update_stars', value, this.disabled);

      if (!this.disabled) {
        // Make some call to a Laravel API using Vue.Resource

        this.temp_value = value;
        return this.mutableValue = value;
      }
    }
  }

});
```

And here is how I display it:

```
<div v-for="review in reviews" class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            ${review.vote} <!-- HERE I SEE THE RIGHT AMOUNT -->
            <star-rating :value="review.vote" :disabled="true"> <!-- HERE I AM PASSING THE SAME AMOUNT BUT GETTING THE WRONG AMOUNT OF STARS -->
            </star-rating>
            <h4 style="display: inline-block !important; font-weight: bold !important;">${review.title}</h4> by
            ${review.current_user_name}
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
....
```

Comment: Can you replicate this issue e.g. on JSFiddle or JSbin ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saying "passing" in the parent component? The request made to laravel is in the child and according to my experience, setting the mutable value in the child and emitting an event to the parent after the request works fine. However, if you're really passing the new value from the parent, the mutable value won't be updated, since `mutableValue` will only be set to `value` when the child's data is created. Subsequent changes of prop `value` won't change `mutableValue`(tested in my project).